# How to sequence the column sort order while fetching data from Dataverse using client sdk?

Tags: sdk, dataverse

How to specify the order of columns (sequence) while sorting the records using 'Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client' SDK?  I have parent table called Location and a child table LocationSortOrder, i have used linked entities with left outer join and trying to sort the entities first by LocationSortOrder.SortOrderValue column and then the Location.LocationCode column.  I have below code which does not give the desired result.

**(Table: Columns)**
**Location:** LocationCode, Description
**LocationSortOrder:** LocationCode, SortOrderValue

```
    var parentQueryExpression = new QueryExpression(locationEntityName)
            {
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(columns),
                NoLock = true
            };
    
    var linkedEntity = new LinkEntity
    {
        LinkFromEntityName = locationEntityName,
        LinkToEntityName = locationSortOrderEntityName,
        LinkFromAttributeName = locationIDName,
        LinkToAttributeName = locationCodeName,
        JoinOperator = JoinOperator.LeftOuter,
        EntityAlias = "locationSortOrder",
        Columns = new ColumnSet(columnNames)
    };
    
    //(1)//linkedEntity.Orders.Add(new OrderExpression("sortOrderValue", OrderType.Ascending, "Location1SortOrder", locationSortOrderEntityName));
    
    parentQueryExpression.LinkEntities.Add(linkedEntity);
    
    var orderExpressionCollection = new Collection<OrderExpression>
        {
            //(2)//new OrderExpression("sortOrderValue", OrderType.Ascending, "Location1SortOrder", locationSortOrderEntityName),
            new OrderExpression(locationCodeName, OrderType.Ascending, "LocationCode", locationEntityName)
        };
parentQueryExpression.Orders.AddRange(orderExpressionCollection);
```

Uncommenting **//(2)//** gives binding error for column 'sortOrderValue'.  Uncommenting //(1)// does not sort the column first by 'sortOrderValue' and then by 'locationCode'.

Update:  Sorting on locationCode in LocationSortOrder table is not an option because not every record from Location is present in LocationSortOrder table.